# Prove that $v \in U^\perp $.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> Let $U$ be a subspace of $V$. Assume that there exists $v\in V$ such that $\langle v,u\rangle +\langle u,v\rangle \le \langle u,u\rangle \forall u\in U$
>
> Prove that $v \in  U^\perp $.

Let $u\in U$ then we need to show that $\langle u,v\rangle =0$

Now $\langle v,u\rangle +\langle u,v\rangle \le \langle u,u\rangle\implies 2\Re \langle u,v\rangle\le \langle u,u\rangle$

How to show from here that $\langle u,v\rangle =0$?

Please help

Comment: So, $V$ are complex inner product vector?

Comment: Hint: look at the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $U$ (i.e. using the fact that $V = U \oplus U^{\perp}$).

Comment: @Chessanator;how is that a hint

Answer (score 2):

We take the Chessanator hint, and note that $U\cap U^{\perp}=\{0\},$ the zero vector. If $v=0,$ then we are done trivially because $0\in U^{\perp}.$ But now, suppose, by way of establishing a contradiction, that $v\in V,$ and $v\not=0$. Then, by assumption, we can write $v=u+u^{\perp},$ where $u\in U$ and $u^{\perp}\in U^{\perp}$. It must be that
$$\langle v,u\rangle+\langle u,v\rangle=\langle u+u^{\perp},u\rangle+\langle u,u+u^{\perp}\rangle=\langle u,u\rangle+\langle u,u\rangle =2\langle u,u\rangle.$$
If $u=0,$ we are done and $v\in U^{\perp}.$ If $u\not=0,$ then we have a case where $\langle v,u\rangle+\langle u,v\rangle > \langle u,u\rangle,$ which cannot be, by assumption. Therefore, $u=0,$ and the theorem is proved.

Comment: $V=U\oplus U^\perp$,how does that mean that if $v\notin U\implies v\in U^\perp$

Comment: I already made it clear that $U\cap U^{\perp}=\{0\}$. There's only one vector in both $U$ and $U^{\perp}$. And, in the case where $v\not=0,$ if it's in $V$ but not $U,$ it must be in $U^{\perp}.$

Comment: Join_PhD has a point. I would propose the following fix. We only know that $v\in V$ so we know that $v=v_{1}+v_{2}$ with $v_{1}\in U$ and $v_{2}\in U^{\perp}$. Then $\langle v_{1},v\rangle+\langle v,v_{1}\rangle=2\langle v_{1},v_{1}\rangle>\langle v_{1},v_{1}\rangle$.

Comment: I think with that change this proof is definitely more elegant than my own.

Comment: @FlorisClaassens how is this true $\langle v_1,v\rangle +\langle v,v_1\rangle =2\langle v_1,v_1\rangle $

Comment: Took me a bit to understand the objection, but thanks @FlorisClaassens for pointing that out; I trust my changed proof is correct now?

Comment: $\langle v_{1},v\rangle=\langle v_{1},v_{1}+v_{2}\rangle=\langle v_{1},v_{1}\rangle+\langle v_{1},v_{2}\rangle=\langle v_{1},v_{1}\rangle$ as $v_{2}\in U^{\perp}$.

Comment: @Adrian Keister, yes that looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is some $u\in U$ such that $\langle u,v\rangle\neq 0$. Pick $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ and take $w=\lambda u$, such that $\langle w,v\rangle>0$ and $\|w\|=1$.

Now let $r>0$ and consider
$$\langle v,rw\rangle+\langle rw,v\rangle\leq \|rw\|^{2}=r^{2}\Leftrightarrow r^{2}-2r\langle v,w\rangle\geq0$$
which only holds for $r\leq0$ and $r\geq 2\langle v,w\rangle$. So for $r=\langle v,w\rangle$ we find
$$\langle v,rw\rangle+\langle rw,v\rangle=2\langle v,w\rangle^{2}\geq \langle v,w\rangle^{2}=\|rw\|^{2}$$
which is a contradiction.